# Can anyone identify this octagonal dish piece for me?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

It seems like this piece would be named "**Octagonal Dish 2 x 2**" but I can't seem to find it on any of the usual sites. Is this named something else or is it not a real LEGO element?

[image: Octagonal Dish 2 x 2]

Comment: Does the part have any numbering / lettering?

Answer (score 7):

I believe it's yet another MEGABLOKS part. You can see it on the top of [9321 Cyborian rover](http://en.bricker.ru/osets/MEGABLOKS/9321/) holding the yellow antenna, for example.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm going with "This is not a LEGO piece", assuming completeness of this Brickset page: http://www.brickset.com/parts/browse/categories/?category=Plates,%20Special%20Circles%20And%20Angles which seems to be where it would be if it existed in genuine LEGO...

Answer (score 2):

It is very obvious that it is a Mega Blok.

1. Mega Bloks are always thicker than Lego bricks.
2. It would have Lego markings on it.
3. It would be listed [here](http://www.brickset.com/parts/browse/categories/?category=Plates,%20Special%20Circles%20And%20Angles).
4. Have you seen a Lego piece with those big bumps? I have seen them on lots of Mega Bloks.

Comment: +1: In this case you're quite right. In general, however, it is worth noting that LEGO isn't always marked as such (Minitalia components, for example), and that the list on Brickset isn't quite definitive.

Answer (score -1):

It could be the extension to the gun like objects in the Lego Life on Mars set.